# Using an array of indicies to build an Astropy table

Tags: python-3.x, datatable, astropy

I have two catalogs  I want to build into an Astropy table and I can't seem to make it work. Both the arrays are different length and I have a third array which contains indices I need to use  to build the table. The two catalogs look as follows:

```
c1['x'] = [11.7, 13.8, 19.2, 15.0]
c2['x'] = [12.0, 13.6, 14.5]
idx = [0, 2]
```

I need to create a table that only includes the first and third entries in the two catalogs. I have tried:

```
from astropy.table import Table
t = Table([idx, c1, cat2], names=('idx', 'x', 'x'))   
t
```

This gives me an error: "Inconsistent data column lengths: {4, 3}" I feel I may be going about this a strange way.

Answer (score 1):

Use Numpy arrays instead of Python lists to represent your data, and apply the row selection index `idx` before creating the `Table`.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from astropy.table import Table
>>> c1x = np.array([11.7, 13.8, 19.2, 15.0])
>>> c2x = np.array([12.0, 13.6, 14.5])
>>> idx = np.array([0, 2])
>>> c1x[idx]
array([11.7, 19.2])
>>> c2x[idx]
array([12. , 14.5])
>>> table = Table()
>>> table['c1x'] = c1x[idx]
>>> table['c2x'] = c2x[idx]
>>> table
<Table length=2>
  c1x     c2x  
float64 float64
------- -------
   11.7    12.0
   19.2    14.5
```

Astropy Table internally stores data as Numpy arrays, so if you already have two tables `c1` and `c2` you could do this:

```
>>> c1 = Table()
>>> c1['x'] = [11.7, 13.8, 19.2, 15.0]
>>> c2 = Table()
>>> c2['x'] = [12.0, 13.6, 14.5]
>>> idx = [0, 2]
>>> t = Table()
>>> t['c1x'] = c1['x'][idx]
>>> t['c2x'] = c2['x'][idx]
>>> t
<Table length=2>
  c1x     c2x  
float64 float64
------- -------
   11.7    12.0
   19.2    14.5
```

There are many different ways to create tables, to select rows and columns from them, or to combine data from two tables into a new table. E.g. in your case you might want to apply `idx` to select the relevant rows in each table `c1` and `c2`, and then join the two tables (that now have the same number of rows). See the [Astropy Table docs](http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/table/index.html).

Comment: I see @Christoph . That makes sense but I do get an error when I use an idx array that has indices outside of one of the c arrays. For example, if the idx array were instead idx = [0,3] the code would return an error "index 3 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 2". Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Well, you select rows that aren't there. Python and Astropy Table uses 0-based indexing, so for a list or array or Table with 3 entries, the indices are [0, 1, 2]. You have to make an index array or a boolean mask with the rows you'd like to select.